# DB connection adapter "Data type mismatch"

Tags: c#, sql, adapter

I have succesufuly setup a connection to my acces DB (.mdb) using OleDb.I am encountering a

> "Data type mismatch in criteria expression."

error if I use a "where" statement in the SQL command.If I remove it I succesufuly get all the Comments.

Any ideas?

My database looks something like this:

```
ID (short text)     Comment (long text)
431                 They_study_math
321                 They_study_biology
```

and my code looks like this:

```
public void auth_group(string group)
    {
        connDB.Open();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT Comment FROM groups WHERE ID=431", connDB);
        adapter.Fill(ds);
        connDB.Close();

        DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(dr["Comment"].ToString());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel like your `ID` column is a character type, that's why you should use it with single quotes like;

```
WHERE ID = '431'
```

I have to say this, looks like the right type for your `ID` column is integer not character.

Also use [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your database connections and `OleDbDataAdapter`.

Comment: I tried to use "SELECT Notificari FROM grupe WHERE ID='"+group+"'" but i get "Syntax error in string in query expression 'ID='431' which should be correct...

Comment: @user3605321 This is totally a different query from your question!

Answer (score 0):

your id field is string . you should write like this:

public void auth_group(string group)
    {
        connDB.Open();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT Comment FROM groups WHERE ID='431'", connDB);
        adapter.Fill(ds);
        connDB.Close();

```
    DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(dr["Comment"].ToString());
    }
}
```